# Get status of transfer job using an AWS transfer connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-transfer-family

Boto3 exposes this method: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/transfer/client/start_file_transfer.html

for initiating an sftp transfer job. The method returns a TransferId, however the docs do not include a method that accepts that transfer-id to allow status polling. What is the best practice for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

The only way available, as of Nov 2023 is to check for the status of a file transfer initiated through a AWS transfer family SFTP connector is to monitor the cloud watch logs for updates regarding the file transfer. Connector activity is logged to log streams that have the format of aws/transfer/connector-id.

This is not be best way to check for status of file transfer but this is the only way available for now.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/transfer-sftp-connectors.html